# DRY vs Дзен Python в задаче о троттлинге в Amazon-отчетах

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, dry

Скажу, что вопрос носит общий характер, не требует знания сервисов Amazon.  Нужно "только" ощущение красивого в Puthon ))
Всем известен принцип DRY - не повторяй себя. Он не вошел в Дзен Python в явном виде, возможно из ощущения "общепринятости".  У меня практический вопрос, плюс некоторые рассуждения.  Код не будет повторяемым, меня интересует ответ - конструкция. Как бы вы сделали. Итак, начнем.
У меня есть задача про получение отчетов Amazon через API. Хотя у любого подобного сервиса продаж через сайт есть понятие троттлинг, примененное к получению отчетов. Скажем 15 подряд, а затем 1 в минуту.  Если вы сделаете 16 кряду в цикле, вылетит исключение и надо подождать.  Вот код предлагаемого решения

```
infinity = True
while infinity:
    try:
        request = x.request_report(amz_report_name,
                                   start_date=bytes(auto_report.reportstart, CODING),
                                   end_date=bytes(auto_report.reportend, CODING),
                                   )
        infinity = False
    except Exception as e:
        if TROTTLING_MESSAGE in e:
            time.sleep(61)
        else:
            assert False, f"Unknown error: \n {e}"
```

Важно указать, что типов запросов с полтора десятка и у них могут быть разный набор как ключевых так и позиционных параметров.
То есть везде в коде, где мне нужно получить от Amazon отчет, я должен "обвязать" непосредственное обращение к методу конструкцией `try-except` одного и того же вида.
Одним из напрашивающихся решений в таких случаях -  механизм декораторов.  Ну запихиваем нашу "обвязку" в декоратор, и декорируем необходимый вызов. Однако я вызываю не свои функции а методы модуля `mws`, поэтому для того чтобы применить декоратор, мне нужно для каждого такого метода нужно сделать обертку - функцию, если я не ошибаюсь. Плюс - разные параметры потребуют  использовать `*args, **kwargs` в декораторе.
Итого, я избавляюсь от повторения себя, получаю удобно менять `try-except`  в одном месте, если вдруг понадобится, но при этом придется наплодить оберток методов, оберток на оберток и нарушить три принципа Zen Python:

```
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
 ...
Readability counts.
```

Итого вопрос. Какая конструкция все же лучше - набросать везде понятных и читаемых `try-except` или снизить читаемость и "навертеть" декораторов?  Особенно буду признателен, если поделетись "шаблоном для подобного случая"  из своего опыта.
Ну и да - получается, что это философский вопрос - что важнее **DRY** или **Zen Python**

Что касается меня, то возможно я боюсь сложной отладки связанной с декораторами, которой я еще никогда не делал...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно написать функцию обертку (`wrapper function`):

```
def try_or_sleep(func, retry_count=30, retry_sleep=61, *args, **kwargs):
    for _ in range(retry_count):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            if TROTTLING_MESSAGE in e:
                time.sleep(retry_sleep)
            else:
                assert False, f"Unknown error: \n {e}"
    return None
```

Пример вызова:

```
request = try_or_sleep(
    func=x.request_report,
    retry_count=30,
    retry_sleep=61,
    args=(amz_report_name,),
    start_date=bytes(auto_report.reportstart, CODING),
    end_date=bytes(auto_report.reportend, CODING))
```

Comment: О! похоже это оно!
Цикл я все равно вынесу наружу... Так по логике надо.
А функция - обертка это куда лучше декоратора в данном случае.
Спасибки!!

Comment: если хотите - подправьте ответ.
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Answer (score 1):

Вот к какому решению я пришел, основываясь на идее ответа **@MaxU**.

Мне этот "шаблон" кажется важным и новым, хотя возможно не самым распространенным.
Кратко о проблеме: возникла необходимость декорировать МЕТОД класса из чужого модуля. Можно было бы сделать обертку на метод, превратив его в свою функцию, однако мне показалось это громоздким.  Предлагаемое решение - функция декоратор без декорирования функции при помощи оператора `@`. А прямо в коде явно вызываем декоратор с нужным методом.
Это соблюдает принцип DRY и Дзен  Python.

```
def try_or_sleep(func, sleep_secs=60):
"""
Обертка на метод-запрос для учета троттлинга.

Parameters
----------
func : метод-запрос к Amazon модкля mws.
sleep_secs : количество секунд до возможности обработки сервером нового запрос

Returns
-------
объект mws.request - структурированный ответ сервера Amazon.

"""
print('> декоратор с аргументами...')

def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
    print('до вызова функции', func.__name__)
    infinity = True
    while infinity:
        try:
            request = func(*args, **kwargs)
            break
        except Exception as e:
            if TROTTLING_MESSAGE in str(e):
                print(f"{40*'='} awaiting {sleep_secs} secs")
                time.sleep(sleep_secs + 1)
            else:
                assert False, f"Unknown error: \n {e}"

    print('после вызова функции', func.__name__)
    return request
return decorated
```

И вызов выглядит теперь следующим образом:

```
    request = try_or_sleep(x.request_report)(
                        amz_report_name,
                        start_date=bytes(auto_report.reportstart, CODING),
                        end_date=bytes(auto_report.reportend, CODING),
                        )
```

Теперь, глядя на код, вы видите, что метод `x.request_report` оборачивается в `try_or_sleep(...)`, а его (метода) параметры остались на месте. Как сказано в Дзен Python

```
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
 ...
Readability counts.
```

И - да. Простите код с комментариями и отладочной печатью...